# How to format number with decimal places only if non zero?

Tags: oracle

I would like to format some numbers such as when they have decimals, at most two decimals should be shown, when it's an integer no decimal should be shown.

- 100 is an integer so no decimals should be shown => 100
- 100.259 is not an integer, so show two decimals => 100.26
- 100.2 is not an integer, so show => 100.2
- 0.239 => 0.24

I tried :

```
to_char(mynumber, '99999999999999990D99')
```

But it always shows the decimals even for integers.

For some integration reasons, I can only do it using masks. Is that possible please ?

Thanks
regards,

Comment: When you say "two decimals" do you mean "**at most** two decimals"? In your own example, 100.2 is not an integer, so it should show **two** decimals (according to your explanation in words), so it should be 100.20, but you show the desired result as 100.2.

Comment: @mathguy sorry for the confusion. But yes I need at most two decimals. 100.2 should be 100.2 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to have an optional decimal point *using only Oracle numeric format masks*. You can review [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C) for what options are available.

I think the best you can do is probably the odd behavior of `fm`, which suppresses padding characters. That'll prevent the trailing 0s, but not the decimal point.

```
select to_char(100, 'fm99999999999999990D99') from dual;
select to_char(100.2, 'fm99999999999999990D99') from dual;
select to_char(100.259, 'fm99999999999999990D99') from dual;
```

Output:

```
100.
100.2
100.26
```

I would add an rtrim to get rid of the trailing period, but it sounds like that's not possible for you.

```
rtrim(to_char(100, 'fm99999999999999990D99'),'.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't have format modifiers to do what you need to do. (Why that is, only Oracle knows; the request is perfectly sensible.)

The closest you can come to it is to use a `case` expression in the format model itself, conditional on whether the number is an integer or not. Something like this:

```
with
  sample_inputs (num) as (
    select 200   from dual union all
    select 1.3   from dual union all
    select -11   from dual union all
    select -0.43 from dual union all
    select 0     from dual
  )
select num, to_char(num, 'fm9999999990' || 
                          case when num != trunc(num) then 'D99' end) as formatted
from   sample_inputs
;

   NUM  FORMATTED           
------  --------------------
   200  200                 
   1.3  1.3                 
   -11  -11                 
 -0.43  -0.43               
     0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I just found a solution for similar situation.

```sql
with aux as (
    select 100 num from dual
    union all
    select 100.2 from dual
    union all
    select 100.26 from dual
    union all
    select 100.269 from dual
    union all
    select 0.1 from dual
)
select trim(to_char(trunc(num), '99999990')||to_char(nullif(mod(num, 1), 0))) formatted_num
  from aux
```

Output:

```
FORMATTED_NUM
100
100.2
100.26
100.269
0.1
```